# code run at tests behaves differently than manually tested. Jest + ts + express

Tags: typescript, api, jestjs

I am trying to test controller which looks somehow like this:

```
export const createProperty: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const reqData = req.body;
    const newProperty = new Property(reqData);

    if(newProperty.logo === "test") return res.status(200).json({message: "logo === test"});
    console.log("reqData.logo", reqData.logo);
    console.log("newProperty.logo", newProperty.logo);
    return res.status(300).json({message: "passed test"});
};
```

while testing with nodemon it returns expected value - logo === test if logo is set to 'test', second one if its not. But when i test with jest

```
import { createProperty, updateProperty, deleteProperty } from '@src/api/cm/controllers/properties';
import httpMocks, { MockRequest, MockResponse } from 'node-mocks-http';

jest.mock('@src/api/models/property/property');

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('Property controller', () => {
    let req: MockRequest<any>;
    let res: MockResponse<any>;
    let next: jest.Mock;

    beforeEach(() => {
        req = httpMocks.createRequest();
        res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        next = jest.fn();
    });

    describe('createProperty', () => {
        it("should return 200 if logo equals test", async () => {
            req.body = { logo: 'test' };
            (Mask.findOne as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(null);
            await createProperty(req, res, next);
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
            expect(res._getJSONData()).toEqual({ message: "logo === test" });
        });
    });
});
```

```
console logs show
    console.log
      reqData.logo test
    console.log
      newProperty.logo undefined
```

so sudenly after i create model out of data - my program can read it but tests cant... What is the point of testing, if things might work different inside test environment? Any why they work different? I even have

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: "node",
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '^@src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    },
}
```

set inside jest.config.js

I have tried to run ifs on reqData and while its a work around - I still want to know why it happens.